# JPA non-entity not mapped error with select-new syntax

Tags: jpa, jpql

I'm using the select new syntax to query a non-entity in the database and get a not mapped error...

The object (**not an Entity**):

```
package user;

public class User {
  private int id;
  private String lastName;
  private String firstName;
  private String mail;
}
```

The table (**P042USER**) is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE P042USER (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, lastname VARCHAR(100), firstname VARCHAR(100), email VARCHAR(255));
```

Then i want to do a request with the **select new** syntax:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW user.User(u.id, u.lastname, u.firstname, u.email) FROM P042USER u ORDER BY u.id");
return q.getResultList();
```

Finally i got the error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: P042USER is not mapped
```

Of course it is not mapped, that's why I use the select new syntax... Have you got any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In JPQL you work with entities. In your case what you need is a native query and [SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html). Check this [ConstructorResult](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html) JavaDoc for an example.

Comment: I do not have an Entity, so where do I put the annotation @SqlResultSetMapping ? By the way, it seems very complicated. I've seen many references where select new seems to work... When i use createNativeQuery instead of createQuery, i have another error: Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "NEW" not found;

Comment: It is true that SqlResultSetMapping may only be used on an Entity, however it may be used on any Entity at all, so you just need to place it at an arbitrary entity within your persistence context.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can modify your `User` class to be an entity (annotated by `@Entity`) that can be mapped to a specific table other than your `P042USER` table. For example, you map it to table named `ANOTHER_USER`. When you create new User entities, they can be persisted to your `ANOTHER_USER`. At the same time, when you execute native SQL queries against your `P042USER` table, results of your native SQL can be mapped to the `User` class.

A sample of this implementation can be seen in my github [repo](https://github.com/balagueri21/sample-codes/tree/master/EntityWithConstructorResultMapping).

Comment: The best solution indeed would be to have entities for sure but it is quite a hard work today because there are nearly hundred objects to map (moreover table names and column names don't match object names and fields). No one has a solution with the select new syntax ??